# Spring Batch empty file using FlatFileItemReader xML

Tags: java, spring-batch, xmlbeans, flatfilereader

I'm trying to validate if an input file is empty or has data.
I'm working with spring batch thru XML beans config, my actual config is like:

```
<!-- READERS -->
    <bean id="mgbfItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="strict" value="false" />
        <!-- Read a file -->
        <property name="resource" value="file:///fichtemcomp/datent/#{processDataClass.fileName}" />
        <property name="linesToSkip" value="10" />
        <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />

        <!-- Mapper -->
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <!-- split it -->
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
                        <!-- Valores del layout -->
                        <property name="names" value="name,secondName,lastName" />
                    </bean>
                </property>

                <!-- Wrapper -->
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="com.bbva.mgbf.batch.listeners.ScholarItemReader">
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- END READERS -->
```

In my class Scholar ItemReader, I have something like:

```
@Override
    public Map<String, Object> mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        LOGGER.info("Reading all items \t {}", fieldSet);
        LOGGER.info("FieldCount \t {}", fieldSet.getFieldCount());

        Map<String, Object> dataIn = new HashMap<>(65);
        if (fieldSet.getFieldCount() > 0 && !fieldSet.readString(0).trim().isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.info("in if ");

            for (int i = 0; i < 65; i++) {
                String key = "" + i;
                String value = fieldSet.readString(i);
                dataIn.put(key, value);
            }
        }else{
            dataIn.put("empty", "emptyFile");
        }
        return dataIn;
}
```

But it never entered in the "else " declaration, it just ends the process.

**Anyone knows if there are another way to validate if file is empty or not?**

Comment: Some possible strategy: 1 create a tasklet, before this one, that checks if file exists and if it's empty put the dummy line; 2: use your own ItemReader, extending FlatFileItemReader and overriding doRead method also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fieldSetMapper` is called when the reader has already read a line, so trying to check if the file is empty in the mapper is too late in the process.

> I'm trying to validate if an input file is empty or has data

I would use a pre-validation tasklet step that checks if the file is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

I handled it with a custom [`NoWorkFoundStepExecutionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/common-patterns.html#handlingStepCompletionWhenNoInputIsFound) added to the step which has the `FlatFileItemReader`.

Below is the custom listener:

```
@Component
public class CustomNoWorkFoundStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        final var totalItemsReadInStep = stepExecution.getReadCount();
        if (totalItemsReadInStep == 0) {
            logger.error("Data flat file is empty.");
            stepExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
            return ExitStatus.FAILED;
        }
        logger.info("Total items read from data flat file → [{}]", totalItemsReadInStep);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Below is the configuration of step with item reader, processor, writer and the above custom listener:

```
@Bean
public Step dataInputStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
                                    DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                    FlatFileItemReader<DataRecord> dataReader,
                                    ItemProcessor<DataRecord, DataEntity> dataRecordProcessor,
                                    RepositoryItemWriter<DataEntity> dataRepositoryItemWriter,
                                    CustomNoWorkFoundStepExecutionListener listener) {
    return new StepBuilder("dataInputStep", jobRepository)
            .<DataRecord, DataEntity>chunk(10, transactionManager)
            .reader(dataReader)
            .processor(dataRecordProcessor)
            .writer(dataRepositoryItemWriter)
            .listener(listener)
            .build();
}
```